# Разные действия Click, LongClick и Touch на одно и то же место

Tags: java, android, android-on-click, ontouchlistener

Есть определенные сомнения, но все таки вдруг такое поведение возможно.
Суть: у меня есть FrameLayout ([отсюда](https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602)) с событием onTouch для зуминга. В этом Frame есть несколько элементов, которые принимают события onClick и onLongClick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
        locations.get(i).getView().setOnClickListener(onPoleClick);
        locations.get(i).getView().setOnLongClickListener(onPoleLongClick);
}
```

если я выставляю слушателя на клик - перестает действовать MyFrame.onTouch и поле не зумится. Если убираю - соответственно, сижу без кликов, но с зумящимся полем. Если ставлю `return false;` в MyFrame.onTouch, он также перестает работать.
Пробовал заменить locations.get(i).onClick на onTouch (MotionEvent.UP) - при `return true` клик до Frame не доходит, при `return false` MotionEvent.UP не срабатывает. MotionEvent.DOWN не даст обработать onLongClick...

Дудочка и кувшинчик, в общем. **Может быть есть какой-то способ, чтобы onTouch срабатывал "сквозь" клики?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
public class ZoomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    public ZoomFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ZoomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZoomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean upper = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        if (!upper) {
            // Детектим жесты здесь стандартным детектором 
            // и если зум - отрабатываем и выставляем return true
        }
        return upper;
    }
}
```

Т.е. вид `ZoomFrameLayout` будет забирать себе только зум, а клики уйдут детишкам.

И кстати при таком использовании ScaleDetector будут все события перехватываться (там return true в конце). Можно попробовать что-нибуть вроде `if (scaleDetector.isInProgress()) return true;`

Comment: что-то никак не получается реализовать эту идею... не могу понять, что значит "детектим стандартным детектором и если зум..."? :) весь onTouch туда переносить?

Comment: да, точно, отлично, все заработало! ) только теперь, когда в зуме долго поле таксаешь - onLongClick срабатывает, а если недолго - то все норм )

Comment: Только проснулся ;-) Для победы над longclick надо наверное при драг тоже true возвращать...

Comment: да, я уже придумал, как исправить :) спасибо :)

Answer (score 4):

Просто совместите оба действия в `onTouch`:

```
private int min=50;
private int x, dx;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {   
        x = event.getX();     
    } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        dx = event.getX(); 
        if (Math.abs( dx - x ) > min) {
            // зум
        } else {
            // клик
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: попробовал - начинает некорректно работать onLongClick :-/